# LibGDX how to stop player animation stretching

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, sprite, stretching

For my A level computing project in school I have been creating a 2D Plat-former which is similar in style to the Mega-Man games. So far I have gotten some menus and player methods working like collision detection, movement, and animation. All my player animations are in a single sprite sheet that vary in size so they're not all equal (79x136, 118x128, 88x136, etc.).

This is my specific problem:

**However when playing the game and watching the animations by moving and jumping, it seems like the dimensions of the animations are being stretched or compressed into a specific size, which I believe is 118x140**.

I say this because one of the still animations, for when the player is standing still, is displayed correctly in its proper size, and matches this resolution, and it seems like all the other animations are trying to fit into the same dimensions.

I've had a look around the internet and this site to see if someone had a similar issue but none seem to directly relate to this problem, hence why I'm asking for a solution to this.

This is the code used in my Player.java file, where all aspects of my player are defined:

```
package com.ultimate.robot.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer.Cell;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {

    /** the movement velocity */
    private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();

    private float speed = 240 * 2, gravity = 180 * 1.8f, animationTime = 0;

    private boolean canJump;

    private Animation still, left, right, jump, fall;
    private TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer;

    private String blockedKey = "blocked";

    public Player(Animation still, Animation left, Animation right, 
                  Animation jump, Animation fall, TiledMapTileLayer 
                  collisionLayer) {

        super(still.getKeyFrame(0));
        this.still = still;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.jump = jump;
        this.fall = fall;
        this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
    }

    public void draw(Batch spriteBatch) {
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(spriteBatch);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        // apply gravity
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta;

        // clamp velocity
        if(velocity.y > speed)
            velocity.y = speed;
        else if(velocity.y < -speed)
            velocity.y = -speed;

        // save old position
        float oldX = getX(), oldY = getY();
        boolean collisionX = false, collisionY = false;

        // move on x
        setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);

        if(velocity.x < 0) // going left
            collisionX = collidesLeft();
        else if(velocity.x > 0) // going right
            collisionX = collidesRight();

        // react to x collision
        if(collisionX) {
            setX(oldX);
            velocity.x = 0;
        }

        // move on y
        setY(getY() + velocity.y * delta * 5f);

        if(velocity.y < 0) // going down
            canJump = collisionY = collidesBottom();
        else if(velocity.y > 0) // going up
            collisionY = collidesTop();

        // react to y collision
        if(collisionY) {
            setY(oldY);
            velocity.y = 0;
        }

        // update animation
        animationTime += delta;
        setRegion(velocity.x < 0 ? left.getKeyFrame(animationTime) :
                  velocity.x > 0 ? right.getKeyFrame(animationTime) :
                  velocity.y > 0 ? jump.getKeyFrame(animationTime) : 
                  velocity.y < 0 ? fall.getKeyFrame(animationTime) : 
                  still.getKeyFrame(animationTime));
    }

    private boolean isCellBlocked(float x, float y) {
        Cell cell = collisionLayer.getCell(
              (int) (x / collisionLayer.getTileWidth()), 
              (int) (y / collisionLayer.getTileHeight()));

        return cell != null && cell.getTile() != null 
           && cell.getTile().getProperties().containsKey(blockedKey);
    }

    public boolean collidesRight() {
        for(float step = 0; step < getHeight();
          step += collisionLayer.getTileHeight() / 2)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + getWidth(), getY() + step))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean collidesLeft() {
        for(float step = 0; step < getHeight(); 
         step += collisionLayer.getTileHeight() / 2)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX(), getY() + step))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean collidesTop() {
        for(float step = 0; step < getWidth();
          step += collisionLayer.getTileWidth() / 2)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + step, getY() + getHeight()))
                return true;
        return false;

    }

    public boolean collidesBottom() {
        for(float step = 0; step < getWidth(); 
          step += collisionLayer.getTileWidth() / 2)
            if(isCellBlocked(getX() + step, getY()))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Vector2 getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public float getGravity() {
        return gravity;
    }

    public void setGravity(float gravity) {
        this.gravity = gravity;
    }

    public TiledMapTileLayer getCollisionLayer() {
        return collisionLayer;
    }

    public void setCollisionLayer(TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
        this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        switch(keycode) {
        case Keys.SPACE:
            if(canJump) {
                velocity.y = speed / 3f;
                canJump = false;
                animationTime = 0;
            }
            break;
        case Keys.LEFT:
            velocity.x = -speed;
            animationTime = 0;
            break;
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            velocity.x = speed;
            animationTime = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        switch(keycode) {
        case Keys.LEFT:
        case Keys.RIGHT:
            velocity.x = 0;
            animationTime = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, 
                             int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, 
                           int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, 
                                int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

this next code is used in the playersheet.sprites file, which acts as the player's texture atlas and contains the regions:

```
playersheet.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
playerstill
  rotate: false
  xy: 363, 272
  size: 118, 140
  orig: 59, 70
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerstill
  rotate: false
  xy: 867, 152
  size: 118, 128
  orig: 59, 64
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 688, 276
  size: 79, 136
  orig: 39, 68
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 481, 272
  size: 92, 140
  orig: 46, 70
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 767, 280
  size: 132, 132
  orig: 66, 66
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 644, 140
  size: 88, 136
  orig: 44, 68
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 422, 132
  size: 98, 140
  orig: 49, 70
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrun
  rotate: false
  xy: 732, 144
  size: 135, 132
  orig: 67, 66
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playershoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 592, 0
  size: 116, 136
  orig: 58, 68
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerjump
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 44
  size: 74, 184
  orig: 74, 184
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerjumpshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 228
  size: 107, 184
  orig: 107, 184
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerfall
  rotate: false
  xy: 186, 76
  size: 108, 168
  orig: 108, 168
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerfallshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 107, 244
  size: 124, 168
  orig: 124, 168
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 294, 132
  size: 128, 140
  orig: 128, 140
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 573, 276
  size: 115, 136
  orig: 115, 136
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 294, 0
  size: 150, 132
  orig: 150, 132
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 520, 136
  size: 124, 136
  orig: 124, 136
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 231, 272
  size: 132, 140
  orig: 132, 140
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerrunshoot
  rotate: false
  xy: 444, 0
  size: 148, 132
  orig: 148, 132
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerblock
  rotate: false
  xy: 708, 8
  size: 136, 132
  orig: 136, 132
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerduck
  rotate: false
  xy: 899, 304
  size: 96, 108
  orig: 96, 108
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playerhurt
  rotate: false
  xy: 844, 48
  size: 136, 96
  orig: 136, 96
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
playervictory
  rotate: false
  xy: 74, 48
  size: 112, 180
  orig: 112, 180
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

and finally this code is used in my LevelOne.java file, which contains all the elements for the level and creates the player:

```
package com.ultimate.robot.levels;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.ultimate.robot.entities.Player;

public class LevelOne implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Music level1music;
    private Sprite desert, blueSky;
    private TextureAtlas playerAtlas;
    private Player player;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/levelone.tmx");

        playerAtlas = new TextureAtlas("Sprites/playersheet.sprites");
        Animation still, left, right, jump, fall;
        still = new Animation(1/2f, playerAtlas.findRegions("playerstill"));
        left = new Animation(1 /6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("playerrun"));
        right = new Animation(1 /6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("playerrun"));
        jump = new Animation(1 /6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("playerjump"));
        fall = new Animation(1 /6f, playerAtlas.findRegions("playerfall"));
        still.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        left.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        right.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        jump.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
        fall.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);

        player = new Player(still, left, right, jump, fall, 
                            (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0));

        player.setPosition(5 * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileWidth(),
                         4 * player.getCollisionLayer().getTileHeight());

        // setting camera
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        // creating background
        desert = new Sprite(new Texture(
               Gdx.files.internal("Backgrounds/desert.png")));
        blueSky = new Sprite(new Texture(
               Gdx.files.internal("Backgrounds/bluesky.png")));

        // creating music
        level1music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(
               Gdx.files.internal("Music/level1.ogg"));

        // playing music
        level1music.setLooping(true);
        level1music.play();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(player);

        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.position.set(player.getX() + player.getWidth() / 2, 
                        player.getY() + player.getHeight() / 2, 0);

        camera.update();

        renderer.setView(camera);

        renderer.getBatch().begin();
        renderer.getBatch().draw(blueSky, 0, 0);
        renderer.getBatch().draw(desert, 0, 0);
        player.draw(renderer.getBatch());
        renderer.getBatch().end();

        renderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        level1music.dispose();
        playerAtlas.dispose();
        desert.getTexture().dispose();
        blueSky.getTexture().dispose();
    }

}
```

I hope this can help find a solution.

Comment: on the other hand I do not know much English, but if you change the title, maybe my answer is accused of wrong/Incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, I've managed to solve it using a custom Animation class whilst following another tutorial, it seems to fix the stretched and compressed animations. It creates a Texture Region which the animations have to fit in but I've set the size to the largest animation so they all fit within the region. I had to re-write a lot of my code but I'm fine with the end result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things, one would do all the same images if only alpha channel *"will consume more memory"* lest varien size with each other, on the other hand you can check that animations have certain resolutions and facilities `yourSprite.size (w, h);` the latter,
although it seems easier, you have to create a function that controls the image you have in the sprite now if this change resolution then in Set the size of the sprite, so only change as they become necessary, and not doing the set if not changed in size, I hope I understand what I mean.

**example for your comments:**

open Gimp for example and create imagen at size 118x140, with alpha channel, create a new layer and paste the image into it, then export it to the format you want eg png "you can merge the layers downwards to join them" but if you have visible and export it is not necessary.

```
inicial size before Gimp           size base 118x140 
 texture size 79x136        texture size 118x140 after export gimp 
 texture size 118x128       texture size 118x140 after export gimp 
 texture size 88x136        texture size 118x140 after export gimp
```

`yourSprite.size(118, 140);`

Comment: So putting all the images into the alpha channel will reduce the variation in size with each other? I understand the second solution but not the first one you suggested.

Comment: @Zodiac Willoughby O'Neill look the example